# Hyperledger Fabric 2.3.3 install TypeScript chaincode issue can't invoke despite chaincode being installed?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Good day to you!

I'm doing some fairly advanced work with Hyperledger Fabric network setup, using Kubernetes and a bunch of custom shell scripts--each with commands inspired by `fabric-samples`--to run each phase of chaincode packaging and installation and I have debugged an issue I'm facing WRT switching an existing HLF project from Go chaincode to TS to the nth degree (have tried all sorts too) and I am baffled as to why it is not working...

I have plenty of context and output I can provide, however in a nutshell:

- the chaincode packages, installs, approves & commits 100% successfully on all three of my peer organizations (org1, org2, org3)
- all `peer lifecycle chaincode <query>` commands return successes (installed, approved, committed)
- each command which can be passed the `--init-required` flag has it, and the `invoke` command uses flag `--isInit`

When trying to invoke however, it throws an error (redacted environment specific outputs):

`make sure the chaincode <cc_name> has been successfully defined on channel <channel_id> and try again: chaincode definition for '<cc_name>' exists, but chaincode is not installed`

Meanwhile, if I query the committed chaincode (works on all 3 orgs):

```sh
peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted -C ${CHANNEL_ID} -n ${CC_NAME} >&log.txt
cat log.txt
```

Outputs:

```sh
Committed chaincode definition for chaincode '<cc_name>' on channel '<channel_id>'
Version: 1.0, Sequence: 1, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc, Approvals: [Org1MSP: true, Org2MSP: true, Org3MSP: true]
```

Also, if I run `peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled`:

```
=========================



Querying installed chaincode inside Docker container [admin] for Organization org1...


Installed chaincodes on peer:
Package ID: <package_id>, Label: <label>

Query installed successful on peer0.org1 on channel allorgs [via admin].


=========================



Querying installed chaincode inside Docker container [admin] for Organization org2...


Installed chaincodes on peer:
Package ID: <package_id>, Label: <label>

Query installed successful on peer0.org2 on channel allorgs [via admin].


=========================



Querying installed chaincode inside Docker container [admin] for Organization org3...


Installed chaincodes on peer:
Package ID: <package_id>, Label: <label>

Query installed successful on peer0.org3 on channel allorgs [via admin].


=========================
```

To all intents and purposes, this is doing everything I have seen it do in the Go examples and should be considered installed, I'm not sure what else to try at this stage. I've had it configured where the package IDs generated on each org are different, but currently they all install the same packaged chaincode so all of those <package_id> entries match.

Finally, just to avoid wasting any time, this is the output for `peer lifecycle chaincode queryapproved ...`:

```
=========================



Querying approved chaincode inside Docker container [admin] for Organization org1...


Approved chaincode definition for chaincode '<cc_name>' on channel '<channel_id>':
sequence: 1, version: 1.0, init-required: true, package-id: <package_id>, endorsement plugin: escc, validation plugin: vscc

Query approved successful on peer0.org1 on channel <channel_id> [via admin].


=========================



Querying approved chaincode inside Docker container [admin] for Organization org2...


Approved chaincode definition for chaincode '<cc_name>' on channel '<channel_id>':
sequence: 1, version: 1.0, init-required: true, package-id: <package_id>, endorsement plugin: escc, validation plugin: vscc

Query approved successful on peer0.org2 on channel <channel_id> [via admin].


=========================



Querying approved chaincode inside Docker container [admin] for Organization org3...


Approved chaincode definition for chaincode '<cc_name>' on channel '<channel_id>':
sequence: 1, version: 1.0, init-required: true, package-id: <package_id>, endorsement plugin: escc, validation plugin: vscc

Query approved successful on peer0.org3 on channel <channel_id> [via admin].


=========================
```

Is it possible this error is happening for some other unclear reason such as the chaincode failing to execute... or? All suggestions welcome. I tried asking in the Hyperledger chat but no response from anyone there yet.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely remember having a similar problem and you need to make sure package-ids and labels match up. Look on your peers where the chaincode package is installed. If you use the standard docker test images then you can exec into them and look in dir `/var/hyperledger/production/lifecycle/chaincodes/`

For example, my package-id is `basic_1.0:db124ba32ae478421c66bb26fcd151326ae4ce5fa01e198a7ad9415ce31aa8c4` my chaincode name is `basic` and the version is `1.0` when creating the chaincode definition

my installed chaincode

```
/var/hyperledger/production/lifecycle/chaincodes # ls
basic_1.0.db124ba32ae478421c66bb26fcd151326ae4ce5fa01e198a7ad9415ce31aa8c4.tar.gz
```

my packaged chaincode metadata is

```
{"path":"../../chaincode/node","type":"node","label":"basic_1.0"}
```

Make sure everything matches correctly (the label is a concatenation of name and version)

Comment: interesting, thanks. That's not an immediately obvious thing (I don't think I've read that anywhere) and a good potential candidate for a fix for some people (take my upvote!)... however mine are already set identically :(

Comment: Everything has to align exactly, 1 the file is present on the peer, 2 that it has the correct file name, 3 that the metadata label property in that package is correct. Are you saying that all those are correct in your case on all your peers ?

Comment: it isn't to do with the naming issue, however let me check the other part you mentioned because I haven't explicitly tried going to that directory! I will report back shortly, thanks

Comment: yes the file is stored on my peer in that directory for all three organizations... I'll try looking at the metadata now too

Comment: right, interesting.... so inside the metadata the path stored is relative to the root of my project, i.e.:

`{"path":"./directory/inside/my/project/with/typescript", "type": "node", "label": "<label>"}`

This obviously works for all of the phases (the PWD is the root of the project) and no errors thrown (it picks up the code just fine every time). I have a mounted volume from my absolute path in my project (for the chaincode) to the directory being outputted in metadata.json from the very root of the docker container (same dir as `etc`)

Comment: path may be a red herring here as I think it's ignored for node chaincode

Comment: yes to be honest I didn't think that would realistically be the root cause of any issue--all the things you suggested seemed the most critical and they all match up...

Comment: I'm racking my brain to think of anything else I can possibly try. It's so strange!